# Unit Testing Code with WeakReference

Tags: c#, unit-testing, weak-references

I didn't create the framework but I need to write test for it. The scenario...

- It uses WeakReference to hold an object, there's a base method that I call to assign object to it (BaseClass.Register(weakObject))
- I can retrieve that object through a method (BaseClass.GetObject())
- Testing it... I had to register my mock (BaseClass.Register(mockWeak.Object)) first

When executing a method that relies on the registered object, my test sometimes fails because it has been garbage collected before i performed test to it.

Can I do something to prevent GC from collecting my WeakReference object?

NOTE: No changes should be done in the framework (BaseClass), only in my test class

Comment: Keep a non-weak reference (aka a reference) lurking around also? People usually have more trouble properly testing the scenarios where you want the object to be collected.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the test code and the code under test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I found an answer to this... During testing you should make use of...

```
GC.KeepAlive(weakObject)
```

Full reference here.

http://defragdev.com/blog/?p=129